# GitLab Code-Quality to run only on changed files in Merge Request

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, code-climate

Do we have any option in GitLab **code_quality** to run only changed files in source repository? Right now, **code_quality** is analysing the entire project, and the artefacts it produces are enormous. We want to gradually make them better. Here is my .git.ci.yaml configuration

```
stages:
    test
include:
    template: Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml
code_quality: 
    rules: - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" 
    variables: 
        REPORT_FORMAT: html 
    services:
    artifacts: 
        paths: [gl-code-quality-report.html]
    stage: test 
    tags: - ode-quality
```

I am currently referring GitLab official documentation [code_quality](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/code_quality.html) and I have tried various way using Script, When, except options. But none worked out to analyse only changed files. I also saw an open [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/3607) on this.

Can anyone please let me know if we have any way to run **code_quality** analysis only for modified files ?